# How to read terms under a particular termset

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model

I have a termstore like below (sample one)

[image]

i need to write a JSOM code to get sub terms under a particular term set 
As an example once i put My term set's uniquie ID i should reterive My term1,2,3 as my out put

Thank you much.

I followed following code but it does not give proper outcome.

```
function showTermSets(groupId) {

//we need to load and populate the matching group first, or the term sets that it contains will be inaccessible to our code.

var groupEnum = groups.getEnumerator();

while (groupEnum.moveNext()) {

var currentGroup = groupEnum.get_current();

if (currentGroup.get_id() == groupId) {

context.load(currentGroup);

context.executeQueryAsync(

function(){

//Get Term Sets and load them.

var termSets = currentGroup.get_termSets();

context.load(termSets);

context.executeQueryAsync(

function(){

var termSetEnum = termSets.getEnumerator();

var termSetList = "Term Sets: \n"

while(termSetEnum.moveNext()){

var currentTermSet = termSetEnum.get_current();

var termSetName = currentTermSet.get_name();

var termSetId = currentTermSet.get_id();

termSetList += termSetName + ": " + termSetId + "\n";

}

alert(termSetList);

},

function(){

//Failure loading Term Sets

});

},

function () {

//Failure loading Group.

});

break;

}

}

}
```

Answer (score 8):

Please see below code for getting all terms in a termset by using termsetid. The Key thing is making sure SP.js,sp.runtime.js and sp.taxonomy.js are loaded before you make a call to taxonomy store.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {        
        //This makes sure all necessary Js files are loaded before you call taxonomy store
        SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.runtime.js', false, function () {
            SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () {
                SP.SOD.registerSod('sp.taxonomy.js', SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl('sp.taxonomy.js'));//loads sp.taxonomy.js file
                SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.taxonomy.js', false, GetTermsFromTaxonomyStore);
            });
        });
    });



    //This method uses the Taxonomy client side object calls to get the terms 
    function GetTermsFromTaxonomyStore() {

        //Current Context
        var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        //Current Taxonomy Session
        var taxSession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(context);
        //Term Store under which to create the term.
        var termStore = taxSession.getDefaultSiteCollectionTermStore();
         //Pass ID of the Meetings Term Set
        var termSet = termStore.getTermSet("termsetid here");
        var terms = termSet.get_terms();
        context.load(terms);
        context.executeQueryAsync(function () {
            var termEnumerator = terms.getEnumerator();
            while (termEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                var currentTerm = termEnumerator.get_current();
                console.log(currentTerm.get_name());
            }
        }, function (sender, args) {
            console.log(args.get_message());
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this it is very helpful. How do I enumerate through the children of a term? In the OP there is My Term 1 which has children, how would we see those.

Comment: Thank you it is very use full and it work perfectly..
Thank you very much........

Comment: One more question, is it possible to get termsetid by giving termset name?

Comment: @SharePointLearner https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn269605.aspx . See this link

Answer (score -2):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script> 
<link href="/sites/Search3/Style%20Library/scripts/taxonomypickercontrol.css" rel="stylesheet"/> 
<script src="/sites/Search3/Style%20Library/scripts/taxonomypickercontrol.js" 
type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/sites/Search3/Style%20Library/scripts/taxonomypickercontrol_resources.en.js" 
type="text/javascript"></script> 

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){     
    var scriptbase = "http://SharePoint/search/_layouts/15/";   
    $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Runtime.js",
        function () {
            $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.js", function(){
                    $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Taxonomy.js", execOperation);
            });
        }
    );
});


function execOperation(){   
    //Current Context
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();   

    //Current Taxonomy Session
    var taxSession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(context);

    //Term Stores
    var termStores = taxSession.get_termStores();

    //Name of the Term Store from which to get the Terms.
    var termStore = termStores.getByName("Managed Metadata Service Application");

    //GUID of Term Set from which to get the Terms.
    var termSet = termStore.getTermSet("833e401a-6fcb-476c-8d28-61166689c088");

    var terms = termSet.getAllTerms();

    context.load(terms);

    context.executeQueryAsync(function(){

    var termEnumerator = terms.getEnumerator();

    var termList = "Terms: \n";

        while(termEnumerator.moveNext()){

            var currentTerm = termEnumerator.get_current();

            termList += currentTerm.get_name() + ", ";  
        }       
          alert(termList);          
    },function(sender,args){    
          console.log(args.get_message());  
    }); 
}
</script>
```

Comment: It is good if you provide the little description about the code so one can understand it easily.